# Unable to bind image in a td using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to bind a image in ASP.net MVC4 inside a TD, and write the following script, but it shows an error at 
`"html += "<td>" + "<a>" + "<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icon_delete.png")" alt="Delete" title="Delete Structure" />" + "</a>" +"`  so can anyone explain how it should be bind :

```
          $('#UpdateStructure').click(function () {

                var structName = $('#txtStructName').val();
                var BldgAge = $('#ddlBldgAge').val();
                var AvgCapacity = $('#txtAvgCap').val();
                var PckCpcty = $('#txtPkCap').val();
                var tenure = $('#ddlTenure').val();
                var Storeys = $('#ddlStorey').val();
                var Condition = $('#ddlCondition').val();
                var StructureID= $('#txtStructureID').val(); 
                alert("Inside Update Structure"); 



                $.getJSON("../L0S/UpdateStructure", { structName: structName, bldgAge: BldgAge, avgCapacity: AvgCapacity, pkCapacity: PckCpcty, tenure: tenure, StructureID:StructureID }, function (data) {


                    $('#tbdydata').html('');
                    var FinalHTML = '';
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        var html = "<tr><td>" + item.StructureName + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + item.BuildingAge + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + item.AvgCapacity + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + item.peakCapacity + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + item.tenure + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + item.storeys + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + item.condition + "</td></tr>";
                        //html += "<td>" + item.StructureID + "</td></tr>";
                        html += "<td>" + "<a>" + 
                         "<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icon_delete.png")" alt="Delete" title="Delete Structure" />" + "</a>" + 
                         "<a>" +  "<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icon_edit.png")" alt="view" title="Edit Structure Details"/>" +  "</a>" + "</td>"
                        //alert(html);
                        FinalHTML = FinalHTML + html;
                        //alert(FinalHTML);                       
                    });
                    $('#tbdydata').html(FinalHTML);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

u may need to escape quotes i think.

```
html += "<td>" + "<a>" + 
                     "<img src=\"@Url.Content(\"~/Images/icon_delete.png\")\" alt=\"Delete\" title=\"Delete Structure\" />" + "</a>" + 
                     "<a>" +  "<img src=\"@Url.Content(\"~/Images/icon_edit.png\")\" alt=\"view\" title=\"Edit Structure Details\"/>" +  "</a>" + "</td>"
                    //alert(html);
```